# Cannot reference jQuery .js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can create a jQuery function within my HTML no problem:

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="mainInput" />
<button class="btn" id="mainButton"></button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mainButton").click(function () {
            $("#mainInput").hide("slow");
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

This does exactly what I intend it to do.

I read it was a good idea to create a separate script to contain the actual function, so I put the script in its own file...

```
<body>

    <input type="text" id="mainInput" />
    <button class="btn" id="mainButton"></button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/jQueryPractice.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here is the .js file with the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainButton").click(function () {            
        $("#mainInput").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

As soon as I do this, the functionality no longer works.
From everything I have researched, this should be working as intended; I have read multiple tutorials that use this method. I must be missing something simple...

Comment: Does `~/js/jQueryPractice.js` load successfully when you load the page?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, what URL does `~/js/jQueryPractice.js` get requested as?  What is the server's response?

Answer (score 1):

This path:

```
src="~/js/jQueryPractice.js"
```

Uses `~`, which doesn't really mean anything to a browser.  What URL do you expect that to refer to?  Should it be the root of the server?:

```
src="/js/jQueryPractice.js"
```

Relative to the page?:

```
src="./js/jQueryPractice.js"
```

Something else?

Whatever the URL is for the script, relative or absolute, that's what needs to be used in the `src` attribute.

Comment: I dragged the script into the HTML from the Solution Explorer. The ~ included itself when I did that.

I also tried different paths, including the ones you suggested. They did not work either.

I checked the browser tools, and they are showing that the script is not being found. It says 'failed to load resource'.

Comment: @BenjaminApprill: "Solution Explorer"?  Are you using Visual Studio for this?  It sounds like that action produced incorrect output.  When you correct it as suggested, does that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio. Someone removed the asp.net tag I put on the question.

Comment: @BenjaminApprill: Well, this doesn't really have anything to do with ASP.NET.  This is just HTML and JavaScript and is happening entirely within the browser.  The URL for the linked JavaScript resource just appears to be invalid, that's all.  Regardless of how it got that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what got it to work.

My project has a 'wwwroot' directory. It was included when generating a new ASP.NET Core application through Visual Studio.

There is a js folder inside of this. When I put my script in there, the browser started finding it successfully.

This was the HTML:

```
<script src="~/js/jQueryPractice.js"></script>
```

The '~' seems to refer to 'wwwroot'. The script is now referencing and behaving as intended.